# xlApp = GetObject line error

Tags: vb.net

1. Ended all EXCEL.EXE processes from Windows Task Manager
2. Run following code.

   ```
   Process.Start("Excel.exe", "/embedded ""C:\Book1.xlsx""")
   Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
   Dim xlApp As Excel.Application = Nothing
   xlApp = CType(GetObject("Excel.Application"), Excel.Application)
   ```
3. See following error.

   ```
   Cannot create ActiveX component
   ```

Any idea?

Supported links:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/291288

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Command-line-switches-for-Excel-c6f24136-e80c-4de9-a0ca-d5c68792cc6f?CTT=1&CorrelationId=f84d4697-fddd-474e-be04-ac843484270e&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HA102919739

Comment: `Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application` is all you need to initialize it.

Comment: Thanks but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of the VB [GetObject Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e9waz863(v=vs.90).aspx) is incorrect.
The method signature is:

```
Public Function GetObject( _
    Optional ByVal PathName As String = Nothing, _
    Optional ByVal [Class] As String = Nothing _
) As Object
```

You are passing a class name ("Excel.Application") as the path argument.

`xlApp = CType(GetObject("Excel.Application"), Excel.Application)`

should be

`xlApp = CType(GetObject(Nothing,"Excel.Application"), Excel.Application)`

Comment: @SamSamuel,  what does "No, there are no any differences" mean?  If you want help, you need to provide meaningful feedback.  The code I showed is valid will work with the one prerequisite of having Excel properly installed on the computer executing the code.